# Looking for a SWS call for a specific host command

Tags: sabre

What is an equivalent SWS call for the following host command:

PI/TRAVELER/823144910-1.1

I am trying to associate a guest profile with a guest on a PNR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have the option to use SabreCommandLLSRQ to send the native PI/TRAVELER/823144910-1.1 command.

```
<SabreCommandLLSRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2003/07" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" EchoToken="String" TimeStamp="2001-12-17T09:30:47-05:00" Target="Production" Version="2003A.TsabreXML1.6.1" SequenceNmbr="1" PrimaryLangID="en-us" AltLangID="en-us">
<Request Output="SCREEN" CDATA="true">
    <HostCommand>PI/TRAVELER/823144910-1.1</HostCommand>
</Request>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to add a Profile Index (PI) to a PNR is to use the ProfileToPNR service that moves the profile into the PNR.